Связь между google-расширением и веб-сайтом
У меня следующая проблема: разрабатываю веб-приложение на FastAPI, которое будет позволять пользователям рассылать письма Gmail через Gmail API; оно разделено на 2 части: веб-сайт и google-расширение, интегрирующее интерфейс в Gmail, работать должно примерно так: на сайте авторизация через google (только через него, т.к. токены нужны для отправки писем) и оплата подписки, а сама рассылка будет проходить через google-расширение, бекенд у них один, на FastAPI, как расширению понимать, что пользователь зарегистрировался на сайте через google и можно пускать его к функционалу

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.
